# 500 Error from PHP upload script

Tags: php

So I've been banging my head against my desk for about a couple of days now trying to figure out is causing this 500 Error. every time I try and post a file image its throws me a error : POST http://example.com/server/uploadProfile.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Not to sure exactly what it means and how to go about and fixing it.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

function image_upload($max_size,$input_file,$path,$new_width) {
if(!define("MAX_SIZE",$max_size)) {
    define("MAX_SIZE",$max_size);
}

    $errors = 0;



    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $img = $_FILES[$input_file]['name'];
    $tmp_file = $_FILES[$input_file]['tmp_name'];

    }

    if($img) {

        $file_name = stripcslashes($_FILES[$input_file]['name']);
        $extension = getExtension($file_name);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


        if($extension != 'jpg' && $extension != 'jpeg' && $extension != 'png' && $extension != 'gif') {
            //echo "Unknown image type.";
            $errors = 1;
            return "Wrong file type.";
        }
        else {
            $size = filesize($_FILES[$input_file]['tmp_name']);

            if($size > MAX_SIZE*1024) {
                $error = 1;
                return "File size too big";
                //echo "You have exceeded the size limit";
            }

            if($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg') {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES[$input_file]['tmp_name'];

                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
            }
            else if($extension == 'png') {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES[$input_file]['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
            }
            else if($extension == 'gif') {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES[$input_file]['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
            }



            list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);


            $newheight = ($height/$width)*$new_width;


            $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$newheight);


                  imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$newheight,$width,$height);

            $rnd = rand(0,9999999999999999999999);

            $file_name = $rnd.'_'.$_FILES[$input_file]['name'];

            $upload_path = $path .$rnd.'_'.$_FILES[$input_file]['name']



            switch($_FILES[$input_file]['type']) {
                case 'image/jpeg':

                        imagejpeg($tmp, $upload_path, 100);


                break;
                case  'image/jpg' :

                    imagejpeg($tmp, $upload_path, 100);



                break;
                case 'image/png':

                        imagepng($tmp, $upload_path, 0);


                break;
                case 'image/gif' :

                        imagegif($tmp, $upload_path);
                break;

            }



        }

    }


}

     function getExtension($str) {

     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; } 
     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
   }

    if(isset($_FILES['profilePhoto']['tmp_name'])) {

   image_upload("320000","profilePhoto","/profile",250);

   }



?>
```

Comment: You have an answer in Apache error log. Please check it, or at least paste here what error you can see there. Google about where you can find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$upload_path = $path .$rnd.'_'.$_FILES[$input_file]['name']
```

You are missing a ; at the end of the line. Syntax errors that make the script uncompilable will result in a server error 500

Comment: Really... lol thats all it was too. Thanks. Not to sure how I kept on missing that. Thanks again!